# NGINX: Redirect a list of deprecated URLs to homepage

Tags: redirect, nginx

I currently have the following location blocks that redirect various URLs to the homepage:

```
location ~ ^/events/?(.*)$ {
    return 301 /;
}

location ~ ^/news/?(.*)$ {
    return 301 /;
}

location ~ ^/about/?(.*)$ {
    return 301 /;
}

...
```

Essentially, `/events, /events/, /news, /news/, /about, /about/` all redirect to `/`.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this that isn't so wet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it setup is perfectly fine, and it's already clean because you can see exactly what you're doing.

If you really want it as one `location` block, this will do the trick:

```
location ~ ^/(events|news|about)?/.*$ {
    return 301 /;
}
```

The explanation:

Here, this location will match any URI in the parentheses and it is optional (?) for it to contain the trailing slash. You don't need `(.*)` because you're not using this part of the string as a back-reference in any way, so you don't need to store it. (You could, of course, and that's okay too.)

Comment: It's a pleasure, glad I could help :)