# How to specify a list of redirect URLs for NGINX in a values.yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, redirect, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We're in the process of migrating from a VM (running a website via IIS) to Kubernetes (ingress via NGINX). We have a list of redirected URLs (old blog posts, some vanity URLs set up for SEO purposes) and when running on IIS, our .NET website defined these redirects in the web.config. Now I'm trying to figure out how to achieve the same in our ingress.yaml.

Or more specifically, in the values.yaml which gets merged into ingress.yaml.

We already have a rule for redirecting non-www URLs to the www equivalent, but in the old web.config we could supply a list like...

```
<rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="all_domains">
    <add key="vanity URL" value="target URL" />
    ...
  </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

And now I would like to declare the same list, but in our values.yaml.

Here is the pertinent section of our current values.yaml...

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($host = 'NON-WWW HOST') {
        rewrite ^ https://www.$host$request_uri permanent;
      }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: www.my-domain.com
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    - host: my-domain.com
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.my-domain.com
      secretName: production-tls
    - hosts:
        - my-domain.com
      secretName: production-without-www-tls
```

Can someone explain how to declare a list of redirect URLs - like [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727350/nginx-redirect-a-list-of-deprecated-urls-to-homepage), but declared in the values.yaml rather than in the NGINX config.